# react render table elements with array.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am currently trying to render an array into a part of a table but it won't render.
All of the values are received correctly.

```
const renderReturnReasons = () => {
      dailyReportDetailItem.returns_explanations.map((returnReason, i) => {
         return (
            <>
               <td>Return-Reason #{i}: </td>
               <td>{returnReason}</td>
            </>
         )
      })
   }
```

dailyReportDetailItem:

```
...
"key1": "key1"
"returns_explanations": [
    "string 1",
    "string 2"
],
...
```

Table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <TdLabel>Retour Count: </TdLabel>
       <TdValue>{dailyReportDetailItem.numberOfReturns}</TdValue>
       {renderReturnReasons()}
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It just won't render that part of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return` the result of your map call, for example:

```
return dailyReportDetailItem.returns_explanations.map(...)
```